# Javascript adding a variable to my anchor tag

Tags: javascript, html

There I am struggling here trying to find a resolution to my following ice of java script.

I have a tree view that I am constructing  that will have clickable branches and I am struggling adding the parameter `+ele.id+`  to the `href` in the anchor tag inside the second span tag.

I have tried every combination I can think of to no avail and researching around the internet has not proved fruitful .

I am fairly new to both javascript and web/ front end design in general so am working my way up a pretty vertical learning curve.   I would be very grateful in deed if any one out there can push me in the right direction to adding my parameter to my `href` URL  or if there is a better way to tackle the problem.

Can anyone help me?

```
// load in the data 
$.ajax({
    url: "/InvalidAddressTreeView/GetSubMenue",
    type: "GET" ,
    data: data ,
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (d) {
        $(this1).removeClass("loadingP");

        if (d.length > 0) {
            var $ul = $("<ul></ul>");
            $.each(d, function (i, ele) {
                $ul.append(
                    $("<li></li>").append(
                        "<span class = 'collapse collapsible' data-loaded = 'false' pid='" + ele.id + "' treelevel ='" + ele.tree_level + "'>&nbsp;</span>" +
                               "<span><a href='/SalesRepAddress/Modify?id='>" + ele.name + "</a></span>"
                    )
                );
            });
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? This `"<span><a href='/SalesRepAddress/Modify?id="+ele.name+"'>"+ele.name+"</a></span>"` ?

Comment: Almost , but instead of using ele.name for the parameter im after ele.id   I think its down the the quotes rapping the span's that are giving me the headache   what im trying (and failing LOL) to do is something like this   "<span><a href='/SalesRepAddress/Modify?id="+ele.id"'>"+ele.name+"</a></span>"

Answer (score 0):

How about creating the elements like :

```
$('<a/>', {
    id: 'foo',
    href: 'http://example..com',
    title: 'ABC',
    text: 'XYZ'
}).appendTo('#mySelector');
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to append the ele.id after the href link? Like this?

`<span><a href='/SalesRepAddress/Modify?id="+ele.id+"'>"+ele.name+"</a></span>`

→ 
`$("a").attr("href", $("a").attr("href") + ele.id));`